# Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start" in generating chart of NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, time-series, chart

I got this error when trying to produce a time-series chart of NDVI in Sentinel-2. I've already tried something like .copyProperties(image)".set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))" but it did not work. How can I solve this?

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
[-52.992228448173776, 5.3639624330339855],
[-52.992228448173776, 5.216962579558439],
[-52.898158013603464, 5.216962579558439],
[-52.898158013603464, 5.3639624330339855]
]]).buffer(1e4)

function toSen2Composite(fromDate, toDate) {
  var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
  ee.Filter.date(fromDate, toDate)

  )

return ee.ImageCollection(
ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
    primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filter(filter),
    secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
})
).map(function (image) {
var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(30)

return 
image.updateMask(cloudFree).divide(10000).copyProperties(image).set('system:time_start', 
image.get('system:time_start'))

})
 .select(
  ['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12'],
  ['Blue','Green','Red','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2'])
 .map(function(image) {
var ndvi = image.expression(
'((NIR - Red) / (NIR + Red))', {
  'NIR': image.select('NIR'),
  'Red': image.select('Red')
}).rename('NDVI')

return image.addBands(ndvi,null,true)
})
.median()
}
function toComposite(fromDate, toDate) {
return toSen2Composite(fromDate, toDate)
}
var composite = toComposite('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
var TS1 = ui.Chart.image.series(composite.select("NDVI"), aoi, ee.Reducer.median(),500, 
'system:time_start')
              .setOptions({
                          title: 'NDVI Time Series',
                          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}, });
print(TS1)
print(composite.bandNames())
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: 'Red,Green,Blue', min: 0, max: 0.3, gamma: 1.6}, 'Sentinel-2')
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fa2696e4c372a20b4ea8c08dc1a24b42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print your output before you try to plot it. Your variable `composite` doesn't contain a property `system:time_start` because you apply a median reducer over the `imageCollection()` which results in a loss of the individual image properties. Remove the median from your mapped function.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/67c6da9efa35fb84c68a0a3ccf947799

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly now